# How to sum the Quarter values into Year values in SAS? Proc SQL?

Tags: sql, sum, sas

I have a data set that contains quarterly data value. But now I want to sum the quarterly values which have the same year.

Data a :

```
time    value
1990Q1  34
1990Q2  12
1990Q3  25
1990Q4  14
2001Q1  29
2001Q2  27
2001Q3  39
2001Q4  20
```

What I want is to sum the quarterly data into year. Like this:

```
time    value
1990    217
2001    194
```

Is there a PROC SQL to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, create a new variable to represent the year and use that in your group by clause. 
You can calculate the year using the substr function.

```
 proc sql;
 create table want as
 select substr(time, 1,4) as QTR, sum(value) as total
 from have
 group by calculated QTR;
 quit;
```

Comment: So, if I want to add one more variable,like:  sum(value2) as total2,how can I do that?